# How to project DTO in DTO Projections with JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, model-view-controller, spring-data-jpa

I need to project dto that is in another dto projection. For example:
I have this 2 DTOs

```
public class FirstDTO{
    private SecondDTO secondDTO;
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    //getters,setters, constructor
}

public class SecondDTO{
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    //getters,setters, constructor
}
```

**FirstDTO** depends on **SecondDTO**, now to solve this issue i thought that i can do something like this:

```
@Repository
public interface FirstDTORepository extends JpaRepository<Company, Long> {

   @Query("SELECT NEW com.mycompany.myproject.dto.FirstDTO(" + 
            "NEW com.mycompany.myproject.dto.SecondDTO(r.id, r.name), " +
            "c.id, " +
            "c.name " +
        ") FROM Company c " +
            "LEFT JOIN c.reports r ") 
   Page<ReportPageDto> findCompanies(Pageable pageable);
}
```

But this doesnt work. I need to project SecondDTO in the query in order to use the pageable sorting. I know some ways to solve this issue (for example we can project everything in one DTO and then split them to 2 DTOs(i dont like this solution)), but this question is not like "I cant solve this problem, please help", but more like "Is there another way of solving this problem?". Please take into account that i am passing Pageable. Thanks in advance :)